# MasterNotDiscoveredException - connecting to elasticsearch running on machine with dyanamic ip using NodeClient

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The environment I'm using is [codeship](http://codeship.io), where `sudo` commands on machines are not allowed,

**(1)** `elasticsearch 1.2.2` node is running at `10.0.3.182` (which is dyanamic ip) with default cluster_name, data and transport ports.

```
[2015-01-12 22:40:06,158][INFO ][node                     ] [Namora] initializing ...
[2015-01-12 22:40:06,162][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Namora] loaded [], sites []
[2015-01-12 22:40:08,332][INFO ][node                     ] [Namora] initialized
[2015-01-12 22:40:08,332][INFO ][node                     ] [Namora] starting ...
[2015-01-12 22:40:08,527][INFO ][transport                ] [Namora] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.3.182:9300]}
[2015-01-12 22:40:11,556][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Namora] new_master [Namora][ay0dhdU2QuSOgLz4dbuu6A][railsonfire_92c081a0-7cd5-0132-88b9-26d15d8e303d_c71873e6021a][inet[/10.0.3.182:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-01-12 22:40:11,583][INFO ][discovery                ] [Namora] elasticsearch/ay0dhdU2QuSOgLz4dbuu6A
[2015-01-12 22:40:11,622][INFO ][http                     ] [Namora] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.3.182:9200]}
[2015-01-12 22:40:11,624][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Namora] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2015-01-12 22:40:11,624][INFO ][node                     ] [Namora] started
```

**Cluster information is** ,

```
$ curl -XGET "10.0.3.182:9200/_cluster/health?pretty=true"
{
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

**(2)** `elasticsearch 1.3.2` is running in the same machine (`10.0.3.182`), data port `9201` and `9301`, with following configuration,

```
################################### Cluster ###################################                     

# Cluster name identifies your cluster for auto-discovery. If you're running                        
# multiple clusters on the same network, make sure you're using unique names.                       
#                                                                                                   
cluster.name: shaharma  

# Set a custom port for the node to node communication (9300 by default):                           
#                                                                                                   
transport.tcp.port: 9301                                                                                                                              

# Enable compression for all communication between nodes (disabled by default):                     
#                                                                                                   
#transport.tcp.compress: true                                                                       

# Set a custom port to listen for HTTP traffic:                                                     
#                                                                                                   
http.port: 9201
```

**es log for which is**

```
[2015-01-12 23:27:36,466][INFO ][node                     ] [Sunstreak] version[1.3.2], pid[47523], build[dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z]
[2015-01-12 23:27:36,467][INFO ][node                     ] [Sunstreak] initializing ...
[2015-01-12 23:27:36,471][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Sunstreak] loaded [], sites []
[2015-01-12 23:27:38,667][INFO ][node                     ] [Sunstreak] initialized
[2015-01-12 23:27:38,668][INFO ][node                     ] [Sunstreak] starting ...
[2015-01-12 23:27:38,796][INFO ][transport                ] [Sunstreak] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9301]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.3.182:9301]}
[2015-01-12 23:27:38,813][INFO ][discovery                ] [Sunstreak] shaharma/7hPpAvJJTSuzR58rIGHccA
[2015-01-12 23:27:41,823][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Sunstreak] new_master [Sunstreak][7hPpAvJJTSuzR58rIGHccA][railsonfire_92c081a0-7cd5-0132-88b9-26d15d8e303d_c71873e6021a][inet[/10.0.3.182:9301]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2015-01-12 23:27:41,859][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Sunstreak] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
[2015-01-12 23:27:41,868][INFO ][http                     ] [Sunstreak] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9201]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.3.182:9201]}
[2015-01-12 23:27:41,869][INFO ][node                     ] [Sunstreak] started
```

**cluster information**,

```
$ curl -XGET "10.0.3.182:9201/_cluster/health?pretty=true"
{
  "cluster_name" : "shaharma",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 0,
  "active_shards" : 0,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0
}
```

**(3)** Now I want to connect to elasticsearch `1.3.2` cluster named `shaharma`, with [NodeClient](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/client.html#node-client) as below,

```
@Override
public Client getObject() throws Exception {
    this.client = nodeBuilder()
            .clusterName("shaharma")
            .client(true)
            .build()
            .start()
            .client();

    return client;
}
```

But, from app it can't find above already running `clusterName` `shaharma`, but starts at `9202` and `9302`.

```
2015-01-12 23:29:07,932 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Belasco] version[1.3.2], pid[48970], build[dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z]
2015-01-12 23:29:07,933 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Belasco] initializing ...
2015-01-12 23:29:07,936 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.plugins] - [Belasco] loaded [], sites []
2015-01-12 23:29:09,262 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Belasco] initialized
2015-01-12 23:29:09,262 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Belasco] starting ...
2015-01-12 23:29:09,373 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.transport] - [Belasco] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9302]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.3.182:9302]}
2015-01-12 23:29:09,389 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.discovery] - [Belasco] shaharma/BXvnMfBwQiSRqrsppuLEhA
2015-01-12 23:29:39,393 WARN (main) [org.elasticsearch.discovery] - [Belasco] waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery
2015-01-12 23:29:39,436 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.http] - [Belasco] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9202]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.3.182:9202]}
2015-01-12 23:29:39,437 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Belasco] started
```

**Cluster information is not available** ,

```
curl -XGET "10.0.3.182:9202/_stats?pretty=true" 
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9202: Connection refused
```

**As app can't connect to elasticsearch, it gives MasterNotDiscovered** `org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [1m]`

Exactly same scenario in localhost **ip** is working fine, as log seen below application node detects the already running node with same `clusterName`.

```
2015-01-13 03:15:45,088 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Electric Eve] version[1.3.2], pid[6262], build[dee175d/2014-08-13T14:29:30Z]
2015-01-13 03:15:45,103 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Electric Eve] initializing ...
2015-01-13 03:15:45,128 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.plugins] - [Electric Eve] loaded [], sites []
2015-01-13 03:15:51,318 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Electric Eve] initialized
2015-01-13 03:15:51,319 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Electric Eve] starting ...
2015-01-13 03:15:51,566 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.transport] - [Electric Eve] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9302]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.1.4:9302]}
2015-01-13 03:15:51,669 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.discovery] - [Electric Eve] shaharma/EhjQEz6tQ_m-x7_j_cAMUw
2015-01-13 03:15:54,889 INFO (elasticsearch[Electric Eve][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]) [org.elasticsearch.cluster.service] - [Electric Eve] detected_master [Professor X][q0poP21MSHKQcCPgtEWkKA][prayagupd][inet[/192.168.1.4:9301]], added {[Professor X][q0poP21MSHKQcCPgtEWkKA][prayagupd][inet[/192.168.1.4:9301]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Professor X][q0poP21MSHKQcCPgtEWkKA][prayagupd][inet[/192.168.1.4:9301]]])
2015-01-13 03:15:54,919 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.http] - [Electric Eve] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9202]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.1.4:9202]}
2015-01-13 03:15:54,921 INFO (main) [org.elasticsearch.node] - [Electric Eve] started
```

#### So, my question is how can I make an application able to detect the already running elasticsearch cluster in a machine with dyanamic ip (Using Elasticsearch NodeClient).

### References

[Elasticsearch server discovery configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8089447/432903)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making following changes fixes this, not sure if this is the best solution instead of using actual ip of machine.

**(1)** Changing `network.host` in `config/elasticsearch.yaml`,

```
network.host: 127.0.0.1
```

**(2)** Explicitly setting `network.host` from `NodeClient`,

```
public Client getObject() throws Exception {
    this.client = nodeBuilder()
            .settings(ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                         .put("cluster.name", "shaharma")
                         .put("network.host", "127.0.0.1"))
            .client(true)
            .build()
            .start()
            .client();

    return client;
}
```